# Set event listener with ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener, event-listener, arrow-functions

**Question:** Why isn't the event listener being set?

```
//ADDING THE EVENT LISTENER
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

//DELCARING INIT, PASSING BLANK PARAM, STATEMENT
var init = () => console.log('Is Firing');
```

Comment: Should have been easy enough to put a breakpoint on the `addEventListener` line and examine the variable `init` at that point. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `init` should be declared first before using it.

```js
//DELCARING INIT, PASSING BLANK PARAM, STATEMENT
var init = () => alert('Is Firing');

//ADDING THE EVENT LISTENER
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: I will got to wait couple more minutes.

Answer (score 0):

init is a function expression , which means hoisting doesn't happen for it, so you should pull the function expression up before the listener binding. I suggest you study the function hoisting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting

Comment: To be precise, the variable `init` **is** hoisted, which is why this does not generate a `ReferenceError`. However, the variable does not acquire a value until the assignment statement is reached, meaning that when referred to in the `addEventListener` call its value is still undefined.